# How can you summon an ender pearl that will teleport you?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I want to use command blocks to summon an ender pearl in a stasis chamber that will teleport me when I activate it. Thing is, I can't figure out how to make the pearl teleport me.

On reddit, I found a comment saying that this script:
`data modify entity @e[type=ender_pearl,limit=1,sort=nearest] Owner set from entity @s UUID`

would make the pearl teleport you. I tried it, and it doesn't do anything. Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?

Comment: I'm curious what the application of this would be. Why not just use a command to teleport you instead of the extra ender pearl? It's an interesting idea.

Comment: It's because I'm trying to find a way to prevent unloaded stasis chambers, actually.
I thought that if a player throws enough pearls, it might cap out and prevent more from working. I want to use command blocks because of the cooldown when a user throws a pearl.

Answer (score 1):

**Your command worked for me.**

After summoning the ender pearl, when you run the `/data` command, make sure it is selecting the nearest ender pearl. You can check if it's `Owner` tag matches yours by using `/data get entity @e[type=minecraft:ender_pearl,limit=1,sort=nearest] Owner` and `/data get entity @s UUID`

---

**If you are summoning many ender pearls in a small area**, it might be that you are selecting the wrong one. You can use:

```
execute as @e[type=ender_pearl,distance=..5] run data modify entity @s Owner set from entity @p UUID
```

This will make all ender pearls within a 5 block spherical radius of the execution point set their `Owner` to the nearest player's `UUID`.

Comment: But will the pearl teleport you when it lands?

Comment: @HyperEdge Yes, it did.